# Create a hook that can fetch data when I want and return a function to fetch and the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to create a custom hook that allows me to fetch some data whenever I like it to do so. The hook should return a function that I can call anywhere within my code to fetch the data, and also a variable that then holds the response. Also, it should return the status of the fetch to me.

My hook looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AppListResponse } from "../../typings/AppListResponse";

const useFetchAppList = (
    userId: string,
    authToken: string
): [() => Promise<void>, (value: React.SetStateAction<string>) => void, string, AppListResponse | null | undefined] => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("idle");
    const [responseData, setData] = useState<AppListResponse | null>();

    const url = `https://my-endpoint.com/lets-fetch-this`;
    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            CustomAuthToken: authToken,
            UserID: userId,
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    const fetchAppList = async (): Promise<void> => {
        setStatus("fetching");

        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, options);
            const json = await response.json();

            setData(json);

            setStatus("successful");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error);
        }
    };

    return [fetchAppList, setStatus, status, responseData];
};

export default useFetchAppList;
```

I try to call it like so:

```
const [fetchAppList, setStatus, status, data] = useFetchAppList(userId, authToken);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
        await fetchAppList();
    };

    fetchData();
    console.log(data, status);
}, []);
```

The problem is that the `console.log(data)` returns `undefined`, and the `status` has the default value it starts with, which is `idle`.

How can I make this work, so that I can call `fetchAppList()` whenever I need, which will in turn return the data I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the component file (second code, where you are calling `useFetchAppList` ), You need to capture the `data` and `status` outside the `useEffect` you specified. The `useEffect` in your code runs only once on initial render and it remembers(closures) the value of `data` and `status` at the time it is invoked. Which is initially set as `undefined` and `"idle"` by the hook `useFetchAppList`.

To see what is actually happening add below code as well to your second file

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data, status);
});
```

You will see different console items. First it would be `"idle"` then it should be `"fetching"` and finally it would be `"successful" or "error"`